# QGIS save raster error

Tags: qgis, geotiff-tiff, export, mapping, save

I got an exception when exporting a .tif image from QGIS.

[image]

> Cannot write raster. Error code: data source creation
> Cannot create new dataset  mymap3.tif:
> Attempt to create 0x0 dataset is illegal,sizes must be larger than zero.

What can the problem be?

Answer (score 7):

Your raster size is 0x0 since your extent is only about 0.08 degrees latitude (the difference between North and South) yet you are asking for a resolution of 2.1174 degrees latitude. Ditto for East-West.

I suspect the 2.1174 (etc) is actually intended to be in metres, and you accidentally have the CRS as 4326 (unprojected, in degrees). If you change to a projected CRS, then it should work.

The hint to give this away - apart from having fallen into the trap of confusing projected units and unprojected units far too often - is the greyed out 0 under Rows and Columns. It is greyed out since you've chosen to specify resolution instead, but it is still linked to your chosen resolution and extent and so it being zero shows there is a problem.

Comment: Thx. Where should i change CRS(i suppose tiff image is in 4326)? What does this resolution setting mean? it was set automatically to 2.1174 and 3.6. The same error happens when i try the same operation for much bigger images(country size images).

Answer (score -1):

Had the same problem and saw the file name. It needs to have the file path name in it.

Example: C:\Users\User\Folder\FileName.tiff

Or click the 3 dots.